# aligning polygon around the edges

Tags: algorithm, lua, polygon

so ive tried to align polygons to achieve something like this: [image]

but i get something like this:

[image]

```
local function signedArea(p, q, r)
    local cross = (q.y - p.y) * (r.x - q.x)
                - (q.x - p.x) * (r.y - q.y)
    return cross
end
  
local function isCCW(p, q, r) return signedArea(p, q, r) < 0 end

local function jarvis_gift_wrapping_algorithm(points)
    local numPoints = #points
    if numPoints < 3 then return end
  
    local leftMostPointIndex = 1
    for i = 1, numPoints do
        if points[i].x < points[leftMostPointIndex].x then
            leftMostPointIndex = i
        end
    end
  
    local p = leftMostPointIndex
    local hull = {}
  
    repeat
        q = points[p + 1] and p + 1 or 1
        for i = 1, numPoints, 1 do
            if isCCW(points[p], points[i], points[q]) then q = i end
        end
  
        table.insert(hull, points[q])
        p = q
    until (p == leftMostPointIndex)
  
    return hull
end
```

and its basically this: https://github.com/kennyledet/Algorithm-Implementations/blob/master/Convex_hull/Lua/Yonaba/convex_hull.lua

if anyone has any idea or know any algorithms that might help me to achieve that i would really appreciate that

Comment: look at [alpha shape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_shape)

Comment: you implemented the convex hull so the result you get is what you should expect. the quesiton is how is "something like this" defined? what's the rule behind the polygon in your first screenshot? we don't know so we cannot help you